# Increasing Audio Device output Gain

Tags: c++, macos, audio, kernel

I want to increase my virtual audio device gain. The Volume is turned all the way up but I can barely hear the audio. To do this I think we should look at the gain `IOAudioLevelControl::createVolumeControl` in IOAudioDevice. This is Soundflower code

```
 // Gain control for each channel
    control = IOAudioLevelControl::createVolumeControl(SoundflowerDevice::kGainMax,         // Initial value
                                                       0,                                   // min value
                                                       SoundflowerDevice::kGainMax,         // max value
                                                       0,                                   // min 0.0 in IOFixed
                                                       (40 << 16) + (32768),                // 72 in IOFixed (16.16)
                                                       channel,                             // kIOAudioControlChannelIDDefaultLeft,
                                                       channelNameMap[channel],             // kIOAudioControlChannelNameLeft,
                                                       channel,                             // control ID - driver-defined
                                                       kIOAudioControlUsageInput);
    addControl(control, (IOAudioControl::IntValueChangeHandler)gainChangeHandler);
```

It seems to me that I should change the 5th argument which does some black magic bit shifting but as I'm not sure how this works and how to change it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 4th and 5th parameters are minDB and maxDB, specified as in integer in 16.16 fixed point format. I think the dB here is meant to be dB relative to digital full scale - meaning that 0 dBFS is the max and the min is a negative value. At the very least, your parameters seem to be reversed and the sign of the positive value is wrong.

The black magic as you call it is specifying a value in the 16.16 fixed point format. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format).

It is setting the maxDB to 40.5.  The 40 coming from bitshifting the 40 up into the integer portion and the 0.5 coming from the 32768.  A much more intuitive way of doing this is using the following method:

Multiply the floating point value by 2^n where n is the number of fractional bits (xx.16) and then round the result.

```
int fixedPtVal = round(40.5 * (1<<16));
```

Back to the issue of what to choose for minDB and maxDB. I couldn't really find any documentation on this but I think you would want to do something like:

```
minDB = round(-40.5 * (1<<16));
maxDB = 0;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work tho.. I have no idea what is going on. I have an equalizer app (its virtual driver ofc is based on Soundflower too)  and it has no problems with the sound volume.  looking through the IORegistry I managed to find its `IOAudioLevelControls`maxDB and minDB values which are 0x488000((72 << 16) + (32768))  and 0 respectively for the gain control. For the Volume  maxDB:0 and minDB:0xffb88000. I tried copying the gain values and use it in the driver but still the same...

Comment: btw I'm using  SoundflowerBed for this sound testing maybe a bug in the app